# How to get a percentage from a range

Tags: algorithm, math

I have a basic math question. I am trying to get a percentage from a range of numbers and the algorithm is troubling me.

Say I have a range of `-5` to `+5` and I want to know what percentage is in between given a value. I know that `-5` would be equivalent to `0%` and `5` would be `100%`, with `0` being `50%`.

I tried to add 5 to bring up the scale, but it just feels like a hack. I would like it to feel dynamic so that I can give it any range and successfully work.

Ex.

```
percent = (5 + value) * 100 / 10
```

How do I figure out what `value` should be the a general case?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

```
range = top_value - bottom_value
percent = (value - bottom_value) / range
```

Comment: Thanks for this! And to the moderator who closed the question, it's NOT difficult to tell what is being asked. It's quite simple.

Comment: This returns float from 0 to 1.

Comment: Yes, it does, for a typical language's definition of 'float'. If a an actual percent is needed, multiply by 100, but note that most random number implementations in most languages provide a number between 0 and 1, so this is probably the simplest form this number can take.

Comment: Btw, I needed the reverse of this so i could get the range value based on the percentage i already had, here's the equation re-worked:

`range = top_value - bottom_value`
    
`value = ((percent / 100) * range) + bottom_value`